# Estimating very low quantile of conditional distribution with regression

Tags: regression

I have about 1 million rows, and I want to estimate Y with 5-10 regressors (X). Not only that, it is important for me to know of a very low percentile. Given X, I want an estimation of a value which Y will not go below 99.99% of times. Y is not normal, but skewed with long tails.

I have had two ideas:

Warped linear regression, and then take out the value corresponding to the percentile from the transformed error distribution. This assumes heteroscedasticity though, however I can not access the data yet to check this assumption.

Quantile regression. I have not used this method before and I am unsure if it is possible to get a good estimate of such low percentile?

Would any of the above ideas be OK for this purpose? And do not hesitate to provide suggestions of other methods, I am a beginner in the field so I have probably missed some relevant alternatives.

Thanks in advance,
Philip

Comment: Qauntile regression can be used for any quantile. How well this will work for your data is a different question that we cannot answer, but having a lot of data certainly helps.

Comment: You might entertain semiparametric models such as the proportional odds model.  These models were created for discrete ordinal Y but work fine for continuous Y, at least up to about 6000 levels if programmed efficiently as in the R `rms` package `orm` function.  A detailed case study is in the [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: @Frank Harrell: What happens above 6,000? Is it just computational burden?

Comment: Yes it's only a computational burden; the super efficient sparse matrix operations that are used make computation time more linear in the number of distinct Y values but after a point it's still slow.  A colleague is working on best approximations, e.g., do you group Y into 5000 quantile intervals or do you round Y to get 5000 distinct values.